# Text editor: How can I duplicate second line to other code

Tags: html, notepad++, text-editor

```html
<a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg">
  <img src="img_forest.jpg">

  <img src="img_forest110.jpg">

  <img src="img_forest228.jpg">

  <img src="img_forest334.jpg">
```

I need to duplicate lines and change the 
`img` src to a `target="_blank"` href for the other lines and keep the img src value the same.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What programming language are you using to generate the code? Or are you wanting to use Javascript?

Comment: i use notepad++

Comment: replace `<img` with `<img target="_blank"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h*<img src=("[^"]+")>`
- Replace with: `<a target="_blank" href="$1">\n$0`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
  *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
\h*         : 0 or more horizontal spaces (space or tabulation)
<img src=   : literally <img src=
(           : start group 1
  "[^"]+"   : 1 or more non quote character between quotes
)           : end group 1
>           : literally >
```

**Replacement:**

```
<a target="_blank" href="$1">   : <a...> tag, with value in group 1 (ie. image filename)
\n                              : linebreak (you could use "\r\n")
$0                              : content of group 0 (ie. the whole match: <img ...>)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg"">
  <img src="img_forest.jpg">

<a target="_blank" href="img_forest110.jpg"">
  <img src="img_forest110.jpg">

<a target="_blank" href="img_forest228.jpg"">
  <img src="img_forest228.jpg">

<a target="_blank" href="img_forest334.jpg"">
  <img src="img_forest334.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use find & replace by Regex:

```
Find: <img src=\"(.*)\"> (you may add / at beginning and ending position if needed)
Replace: <a target="_blank" href="$1"> (add / at beginning or ending if needed)
```

Hope it helps you.